# Lettrine in a subfile produces weird alignment

Tags: typography, subfiles, lettrine

I am trying to typeset a pretty document, and with that comes the need for `lettrine`. When I use it in my `main.tex`, everything works as expected. When I use it in a `subfile`, it works properly when I compile the `subfile` alone, but when I load it into `main.tex` the drop cap is pushed to the margin, like it would if I had set `lhang=1` in `lettrine`.

I am stumped on what is going wrong, any help is appreciated. Minimal working example below:

**main.tex:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\subfile{chap1.tex}
\end{document}
```

**subfile:**

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\lettrine[lines=3]{T}{est} \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

**Output in subfile:**

[image: Outputin subfile]

**Output in main.tex:**

[image: Output in main.tex]

*As a side note, setting `lhang=-1` for a hacky solution doesn't work either.*

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my bad, this was an oversight when porting over my minimal working example. I did have the files in different folders, but wanted to simplify for the question's sake. Fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I think subfiles adds a lot of extra complication, and I'd just use a standard `\input` or `\include` but in this case you need an explicit paragraph end for lettrine to work, so add a blank line

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\lettrine[lines=3]{T}{est} \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: So simple, but it went completely over my head. Thanks!